# pandas dataframe replace full word

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with notes (and other columns). One of the steps in the cleaning process involves replacing abbreviations in the notes. Let's say the notes column is as shown below,

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame(["interesting sting", "an answer", "red and redundant"])
rep = ["sting", "an", "red"]
val = ["string", "no", "blue"]
x.replace(rep,val,inplace=True, regex=True)
print x
```

The above replace results in:

```
interestring string
no noswer
blue nod blueundnot
```

There are several unwanted replacements. I could loop through the list and do a word replace, but I have a very large dataset and looping may not be efficient. I'm also aware of using '\b' for whole word replacement. But I'm not sure how I can do whole word replacement using 'DataFrame.replace' method. Any help will be useful.

Comment: If you replaced your `rep` strings to this it should work: `rep = [r"\bsting\b", r"\ban\b", r"\bred\b"]` this adds breaks at beginning and end so that you don't get matches either in the middle, beg or end of words

Comment: I think for more complex expressions i would write a function and than use pd.DataFrame.apply(). I use it very often and its performance is still ok even at DataFrames that are in len >= 10^6